# Nash equilibrium, a particular matrix game

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, nash-equilibrium

Suppose that we have the following matrix game:

\begin{bmatrix}
   2 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}

What is the **intuition** behind the fact, that the **unique mixed** Nash equilibrium is
$(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$ for the first player? I do not want any computation (or at least very little of computation), just intuition
why on the lower positive element of this matrix $1$ is put more weight
$\frac{2}{3}$ then on the greater element, $2$, on which we put weight $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Is this the payoff matrix for player 1? What is the payoff for player 2? (Is it a zero sum game, so the payoff for player 2 is the negative of the payoff for player 1?)

Comment: I think as this is a matrix game, that the payoff for $2$ is the same as that one for $1$, but I'm not sure.May be you are right with the game being zero sum.I have just derived by $x$ and $y$ this expression: $3xy+1-x-y$ and put them equal to $0$.

Comment: I took the first row with the probability $x$ the second row with p. $1-x$ and similarly for columns $y$ and $1-y$.To what game this computation pertaines?The zero sum game or identicakl matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the possible actions of player $1$ by $U$ and $D$ (up and down) and denote the actions of player $2$ by $L$ and $R$ (left and right).

In a mixed strategy equilibrium, actions played with positive probability must give the same expected payoff. Thus if player 2 plays $L$ and $R$ with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$ respectively, then for player $1$ to play $U$ and $D$ with positive probability it must be that 1's expected payoffs from the two actions are equal:
$$\underbrace{p(2)+(1-p)(0)}_{\text{1's payoff from $U$}}=\underbrace{p(0)+(1-p)(1)}_{\text{1's payoff from $D$}}\quad \iff \quad 2p=1-p.$$

The solution is $p=1/3$, i.e. player 2 has to put twice the weight on $R$ as $L$ in order for player $1$ to be indifferent between playing $U$ and $D$.

The intuition is:

- the payoff for player 1 from $U$ if player 2 plays $L$ is **2** and 0 otherwise
- the payoff for player 1 from $D$ if player 2 plays $R$ is **1** and 0 otherwise
- since $2=2(1)$, player 2 must play $R$ with twice the probability of $L$ in order for player 1 to be indifferent between $U$ and $D$ (i.e. in order for the expected values from $U$ and $D$ to be the same)

Comment: I have an additional question: why your method does not yield the other $2$ equilibria playing $(U,L)$ with probability $1$ and symmetrically playing $(D,R)$ with probability $1$?

Comment: In the equilibria $(U,L)$ and $(D,R)$ the players are both playing pure strategies (i.e. with probability 1 on one of their actions). Thus there is no requirement that they get the same expected payoff from both actions. Generally, the two requirement for strategies played Nash equilibrium are: (i) each player gets the same expected payoff from all actions that they play with positive probability and (ii) each player gets at least as high a payoff from each action they play with positive probability as from each action they play with zero probability.